# permission denied when executing an elf payload

Tags: metasploit, shellcode, msfvenom

I can examine a payload using libemu (sctest) and ndisasm, like this :

```
msfvenom -p linux/x86/shell_bind_tcp -f raw | ./sctest -vvv -Ss 1000

msfvenom -p linux/x86/shell_bind_tcp -f raw | ndisasm -u -
```

And I'd also like to debug the payload with gdb.

So I create an elf executable :

```
msfvenom -p linux/x86/shell_bind_tcp -a x86 --platform linux -f elf > payloadexec
```

But running the payloadexec leads to permission denied.

```
./payloadexec
bash: ./payloadexec: Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you set the executable bit?

Comment: Strange, if I move the file to another folder it works. And it even works if I move it back to original folder.

Comment: @MechMK1 You are right !  Moving to another folder sets the missing exec bit !  I didn't know that permission could change when moving files.

Comment: If you type `chmod +x payloadexec` you will make the file executable.

Comment: Moving a file isn't supposed to set the exe bit. Maybe the original location was mounted with "noexec" option...